# VBA, Extract innertext, excluding specific tags, from HTML

Tags: html, vba, excel

Hello I need to extract specific lines (eg required lines) from HTML, using VBA and excluding some tags (eg span tag).
Here is the HTML example:

```
<div id="main-content">
     <span>...sometext</span>
     required text 1
     required text 2
     <span>...sometext</span>
</div>
```

Here is my VBA code:

```
Excel.ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(11, 11).Value = doc2.GetElementById("main_content").innertext
```

Obviously this returns:

```
...sometext
required text 1
required text 2
...sometext
```

Hence my question for this specific example is to how to extract "required text i" (which doesn't have tags), without "...sometext" (which is contained in the span tag)?

Thanks

Comment: `Split(Split(doc2.GetElementById("main_content").innerHTML, "</span>")(1), "<span>")(0)`

Comment: np can you accept as answer.  thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Split(Split(doc2.GetElementById("main_content").innerHTML, "</span>")(1), "<span>")(0)
```